# How to take notes that expedite reverse search?

Tags: memory, search, microsoft-onenote, writing

I write a diary entry every day and list what I have learned that day there but I often remember I once writing something related to a certain topic but cannot find that entry by keyword searching in the OneNote app. Actually, I title every entry using a keyword but it still cannot help much as it is expected to.

Any suggestions on this? Thanks in advance.